# Frequency categories getting randomly split with table function

Tags: r

I have a large 2 column data frame (`a`) with country codes (ALB, ALG, ...) and years. There are thousands of unordered rows so the countries rows repeat often and randomly:

```
> a
 Country       Year
1     ALB      1991
2     ALB      1993
3     ALB      1994
4     ALB      1994
5     ALB      1996
6     ALG      1996
7     ALG      1971
8     AUS      1942
9     BLG      1998
10    BLG      1923
11    PAR      1957
12    PAR      1994
...
```

I tried `frequency <- data.frame(table(a[,1]))` but it does something really weird. It gives me something like this:

```
    Var1 Freq
1    AFG    1
2    ALB    3
3    ARG    1
4    AUS    1
5    AUT    3
6    AZE    2
7    BEL    3
8    BEN    2
9    BGD    3
10   BIH    4
...
129  ALB   33
130  ALG   73
131  AMS    7
132  ANC    1
133  AND    3
134  ANG   36
135  ANT    4
136  ARG  148
137  ARM   12
138  AUS  268
139  AUT  144
...
```

It'll go through most of the country variables, and then go through them once more, giving me 1 or 2 entries for all Countries. If I add the frequencies up, they'll give me the correct total for their respective countries... but I have no idea why they're getting split like this.

In addition, the countries are getting split at all sorts of random places. The first instance is a relatively small number (no more than 20 with one exception) while the second instance is usually but not always a larger number. Some countries `AFG` only appear in the first instance while others, `ANC` only appear in the second...

Comment: Maybe that column was created with white spaces in it. Try function `trimws`, as in `as.data.frame(table(trimws(a[, 1])))`.

Comment: Show output of `unique(a$Country)`